# How to change standard color displayed in Sharepoint 'Edit mode'

Tags: css, sharepoint, colors

I want to change to change the standard colors in Sharepoint 'Edit Page' mode to new colors [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYLN6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the image you attached, Basically sharepoint OOB giving all basics colors in the font color menu. 
If you are looking for more customization i can share you some articles.

1-  [custom color picker flyout in the SharePoint ribbon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/weslbo/2011/04/21/how-to-create-a-custom-color-picker-flyout-in-the-sharepoint-ribbon/)

2 - [custom style creation for all rich-html-field](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/10/27/custom-styles-for-sharepoint-2010-rich-html-field/)

Please let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, well, the problem i have is when i add some text with some font,and i click on new color to select more custumized colors,the font changes,but when i change it directly from "Standard color",the font still the same

Comment: can you try with selecting all text before applying the colors.